# Java concurrency: CopyOnWriteArrayList behavior

Tags: java, multithreading, java.util.concurrent

I need to store some objects into database.

First of all,

1. I store them on memory (into a collection)
2. When one of them is stored correctly on database, I remove it

So,

```
public class AuditService {
    private CopyOnWriteArrayList<Audit> copyWrite;

    public void flush(Audit... audits) {
        Collection<Audit> auditCollection = Arrays.asList(audits);
        this.copyWrite.addAll(auditCollection);

        this.copyWrite.forEach(audit -> {
            // save audit object on database
            this.copyWrite.remove(audit);

        });
    }
}
```

I has to be thread-safe, I mean, `AuditService` is a singleton class, I several threads can reach at `flush` method at the same time.

My question is:

1. How does `CopyOnWriteArrayList` works exactly in order to solve concurrency.
2. Is this code correct?

Answer (score 1):

`CopyOnWriteArrayList` offers thread safety by copying the underlying array when data changes. Mutator operations like `addAll()` in your example are synchronized internally by `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.

However your code makes little sense, since `copyWrite` field is not accessed outside of the `flush()` method. Local method variables are thread-safe so your code can be simplified to simply:

```
public void flush(Audit... audits) {
    for (Audit a : audits) {
        // save audit object on database
    }
}
```

The problem is what happens if an `Audit` object gets modified. Hopefully you made them immutable as it makes little sense to change `Audit` events.

Comment: audits are first stored on a `CopyOnWriteArrayList` since if  `save audit on database operation` fails, the next time a `flush` is reached, pending audits are going to be tried to be stored again. What do you think about.

Comment: It makes little sense unless you are expecting database server to go down more than application server. It's usually the opposite. Perhaps I don't understand your landscape.

Comment: Do you suggest me another strategy?

Comment: Can it be possible that a same audit object stored in `CopyOnWriteArrayList` is stored twice on database?

Comment: I mean, what happens when two threads reach `forEach`? Are both threads going to "list" the same audits, and then a same audit could be stored twice...?

Comment: @Jordi in this case you most likely want to use database constraints to de-deuplicate. You current Java approach has no de-depulication logic and won't work if you deploy your application twice and have more than one JVM. You probably should ask a new question at this point, it has little to do with `CopyOnWriteArrayList`.